# Как правильно реализовать смещение контента вверх при появлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-layout

Мне необходимо смещать контент вверх при появлении клавиатуры. Как это реализовать правильно и где - в xml  или в коде? Пишу на котлине

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - добавить в манифесте соответствующую пометку которая будет отвечать за изменение размера:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

типа такого:

```
<activity android:name=".Game"  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">

    </activity>
```

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528569/how-to-move-up-the-whole-layout-when-keyboard-shown) есть подобное обсуждение. [Туториал](https://medium.com/@madalinnita/android-how-to-move-views-above-keyboard-when-its-opened-quick-secure-solution-90188c4d7b15) по данному вопросу и [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility)